# How can i bypass Advanced css/js aggregation on a URL

Tags: drupal

I have a node that has javascript and a form for a calculator pasted onto the page that allows users to calculate a score based on the form fields they select.

This only works when I use the bypass cookie feature. I've tried adding ?advagg=0 to the url but that doesn't seem to work at all, the page just reloads.

Is there another way I can bypass only the one URL so that my calculator works?

This is what we pasted to the page:

```
<!-- APS Calculator Script start -->
<script>
    function DetectEnterPressed(e) {
        var characterCode;
        if (e && e.which) {
            e = e;
            characterCode = e.which;
        }
        else {
            e = event;
            characterCode = e.keyCode;
        }
        if (characterCode == 13) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    function validateform(thisform) {
        with (thisform) {

            var e = document.getElementById("FirstLanguage");
            var strFirstLanguage = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            if (document.getElementById("FirstLanguage").options[document.getElementById("FirstLanguage").selectedIndex].value == ""  || document.getElementById("FirstLanguageAPS").options[document.getElementById("FirstLanguageAPS").selectedIndex].value == "") {
                  alert("Please select your First language and mark");
                  document.getElementById("FirstLanguage").focus();
                  return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("SecondLanguage").options[document.getElementById("SecondLanguage").selectedIndex].value == "" || document.getElementById("SecondLanguageAPS").options[document.getElementById("SecondLanguageAPS").selectedIndex].value == "") {
                  alert("Please select your Second language and mark");
                  document.getElementById("SecondLanguage").focus();
                  return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("Maths").options[document.getElementById("Maths").selectedIndex].value == "" || document.getElementById("MathsAPS").options[document.getElementById("MathsAPS").selectedIndex].value == "") {
                  alert("Please select your Math type and mark");
                  document.getElementById("Maths").focus(); ;
                  return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("LO").options[document.getElementById("LO").selectedIndex].value == "" || document.getElementById("LOAPS").options[document.getElementById("LOAPS").selectedIndex].value == "") {
                  alert("Please select your LO mark");
                  document.getElementById("LOAPS").focus();
                  return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("Subject5").options[document.getElementById("Subject5").selectedIndex].value == "" || document.getElementById("Subject5APS").options[document.getElementById("Subject5APS").selectedIndex].value == "") {
                  alert("Please select a fifth subject and mark");
                  document.getElementById("Subject5").focus();
                  return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("Subject6").options[document.getElementById("Subject6").selectedIndex].value == "" || document.getElementById("Subject6APS").options[document.getElementById("Subject6APS").selectedIndex].value == "") {
                  alert("Please select a sixth subject and mark");
                  document.getElementById("Subject6").focus();
                  return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("Subject7").options[document.getElementById("Subject7").selectedIndex].value == "" || document.getElementById("Subject7APS").options[document.getElementById("Subject7APS").selectedIndex].value == "") {
                  alert("Please select a seventh subject and mark");
                  document.getElementById("Subject7").focus();
                  return false;
            }

            var APSscore;

            var FirstLang = parseInt(document.getElementById("FirstLanguageAPS").options[document.getElementById("FirstLanguageAPS").selectedIndex].value)
            var SecondLang = parseInt(document.getElementById("SecondLanguageAPS").options[document.getElementById("SecondLanguageAPS").selectedIndex].value)
            var Maths = parseInt(document.getElementById("MathsAPS").options[document.getElementById("MathsAPS").selectedIndex].value)
            var LO = parseInt(document.getElementById("LOAPS").options[document.getElementById("LOAPS").selectedIndex].value)
            var Subject5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Subject5APS").options[document.getElementById("Subject5APS").selectedIndex].value)
            var Subject6 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Subject6APS").options[document.getElementById("Subject6APS").selectedIndex].value)
            var Subject7 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Subject7APS").options[document.getElementById("Subject7APS").selectedIndex].value)

            APSscore = FirstLang + SecondLang + Maths + LO + Subject5 + Subject6 + Subject7;

            document.getElementById("showScore").innerHTML = "<p class='APSscore'>Your APS score is <strong>" + APSscore + "</strong></p><br />";
            return false;
          }

      }

</script>
<!-- APS Calculator Script end -->

<form action="#" method="post" name="APSCalculator" onsubmit="return (validateform(this))">
<div class="HideTableBorders">
    <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #999;padding: 3px 5px;background-color: #999;color: #fff;border-right: 1px solid #bbb;">
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #999;padding: 3px 5px;background-color: #999;color: #fff;border-right: 1px solid #bbb;">
                    <strong>Subjects:</strong>
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #999;padding: 3px 5px;background-color: #999;color: #fff;border-right: 1px solid #bbb;">
                    <strong>Marks:</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <strong>First Language</strong></td>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="FirstLanguage" name="FirstLanguage">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Select a subject.</option>
                        <option value="Afrikaans Home Language">Afrikaans Home Language</option>
                        <option value="English Home Language">English Home Language</option>
                        <option value="IsiNdebele Home Language">IsiNdebele Home Language</option>
                        <option value="IsiXhosa Home Language">IsiXhosa Home Language</option>
                        <option value="IsiZulu Home Language">IsiZulu Home Language</option>
                        <option value="Sepedi Home Language">Sepedi Home Language</option>
                        <option value="Sesotho Home Language">Sesotho Home Language</option>
                        <option value="Setswana Home Language">Setswana Home Language</option>
                        <option value="SiSwati Home Language">SiSwati Home Language</option>
                        <option value="Tshivenda Home Language">Tshivenda Home Language</option>
                        <option value="Xitsonga Home Language">Xitsonga Home Language</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="FirstLanguageAPS" name="FirstLanguageAPS">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Select your mark.</option>
                        <option value="8">90% - 100% (Level 8)</option>
                        <option value="7">80% - 89% (Level 7)</option>
                        <option value="6">70% - 79% (Level 6)</option>
                        <option value="5">60% - 69% (Level 5)</option>
                        <option value="4">50% - 59% (Level 4)</option>
                        <option value="3">40% - 49% (Level 3)</option>
                        <option value="2">30% - 39% (Level 2)</option>
                        <option value="0">0% - 29% (Level 1)</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Second Language</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="SecondLanguage" name="SecondLanguage">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Select a subject.</option>
                        <option value="Afrikaans First Additional Language">Afrikaans First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="English First Additional Language">English First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="IsiNdebele First Additional Language">IsiNdebele First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="IsiXhosa First Additional Language">IsiXhosa First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="IsiZulu First Additional Language">IsiZulu First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="Sepedi First Additional Language">Sepedi First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="Sesotho First Additional Language">Sesotho First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="Setswana First Additional Language">Setswana First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="SiSwati First Additional Language">SiSwati First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="Tshivenda First Additional Language">Tshivenda First Additional Language</option>
                        <option value="Xitsonga First Additional Language">Xitsonga First Additional Language</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="SecondLanguageAPS" name="SecondLanguageAPS">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Select your mark.</option>
                        <option value="8">90% - 100% (Level 8)</option>
                        <option value="7">80% - 89% (Level 7)</option>
                        <option value="6">70% - 79% (Level 6)</option>
                        <option value="5">60% - 69% (Level 5)</option>
                        <option value="4">50% - 59% (Level 4)</option>
                        <option value="3">40% - 49% (Level 3)</option>
                        <option value="2">30% - 39% (Level 2)</option>
                        <option value="0">0% - 29% (Level 1)</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <strong>Maths</strong></td>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="Maths" name="Maths">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Select a subject.</option>
                        <option value="Mathematical Literacy">Mathematical Literacy</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="MathsAPS" name="MathsAPS">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Select your mark.</option><option value="8">90% - 100% (Level 8)</option><option value="7">80% - 89% (Level 7)</option><option value="6">70% - 79% (Level 6)</option><option value="5">60% - 69% (Level 5)</option><option value="4">50% - 59% (Level 4)</option><option value="3">40% - 49% (Level 3)</option><option value="2">30% - 39% (Level 2)</option><option value="0">0% - 29% (Level 1)</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Life Orientation (LO)</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="LO" name="LO"><option selected="selected" value="Life Orientation">Life Orientation</option></select></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="LOAPS" name="LOAPS"><option selected="selected" value="">Select your mark.</option><option value="8">90% - 100% (Level 8)</option><option value="7">80% - 89% (Level 7)</option><option value="6">70% - 79% (Level 6)</option><option value="5">60% - 69% (Level 5)</option><option value="4">50% - 59% (Level 4)</option><option value="3">40% - 49% (Level 3)</option><option value="2">30% - 39% (Level 2)</option><option value="0">0% - 29% (Level 1)</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <strong>Subject 5</strong></td>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="Subject5" name="Subject5"><option selected="selected" value="">Select a subject.</option><option value="Accounting">Accounting</option><option value="Afrikaans Second Additional Language">Afrikaans Second Additional Language</option><option value="Agricultural Management Practices">Agricultural Management Practices</option><option value="Agricultural Science">Agricultural Science</option><option value="Agricultural Technology">Agricultural Technology</option><option value="Arabic Second Additional Language">Arabic Second Additional Language</option><option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option><option value="Civil Technology">Civil Technology</option><option value="Computer Applications Technology">Computer Applications Technology</option><option value="Consumer Studies">Consumer Studies</option><option value="Dance Studies">Dance Studies</option><option value="Design">Design</option><option value="Dramatic Arts">Dramatic Arts</option><option value="Economics">Economics</option><option value="Electrical Technology">Electrical Technology</option><option value="Engineering Graphics and Design">Engineering Graphics and Design</option><option value="English Second Additional Language">English Second Additional Language</option><option value="French Second Additional Language">French Second Additional Language</option><option value="Geography">Geography</option><option value="German Home Language">German Home Language</option><option value="German Second Additional Language">German Second Additional Language</option><option value="Gujarati First Additional Language">Gujarati First Additional Language</option><option value="Gujarati Home Language">Gujarati Home Language</option><option value="Gujarati Second Additional Language">Gujarati Second Additional Language</option><option value="Hebrew Second Additional Language">Hebrew Second Additional Language</option><option value="Hindi First Additional Language">Hindi First Additional Language</option><option value="Hindi Home Language">Hindi Home Language</option><option value="Hindi Second Additional Language">Hindi Second Additional Language</option><option value="History">History</option><option value="Hospitality Studies">Hospitality Studies</option><option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option><option value="IsiNdebele Second Additional Language">IsiNdebele Second Additional Language</option><option value="IsiXhosa Second Additional Language">IsiXhosa Second Additional Language</option><option value="IsiZulu Second Additional Language">IsiZulu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Italian Second Additional Language">Italian Second Additional Language</option><option value="Latin Second Additional Language">Latin Second Additional Language</option><option value="Life Sciences">Life Sciences</option><option value="Mechanical Technology">Mechanical Technology</option><option value="Music">Music</option><option value="Physical Sciences">Physical Sciences</option><option value="Portuguese First Additional Language">Portuguese First Additional Language</option><option value="Portuguese Home Language">Portuguese Home Language</option><option value="Portuguese Second Additional Language">Portuguese Second Additional Language</option><option value="Religion Studies">Religion Studies</option><option value="Sepedi Second Additional Language">Sepedi Second Additional Language</option><option value="Sesotho Second Additional Language">Sesotho Second Additional Language</option><option value="Setswana Second Additional Language">Setswana Second Additional Language</option><option value="SiSwati Second Additional Language">SiSwati Second Additional Language</option><option value="Spanish Second Additional Language">Spanish Second Additional Language</option><option value="Tamil First Additional Language">Tamil First Additional Language</option><option value="Tamil Home Language">Tamil Home Language</option><option value="Tamil Second Additional Language">Tamil Second Additional Language</option><option value="Telegu First Additional Language">Telegu First Additional Language</option><option value="Telegu Home Language">Telegu Home Language</option><option value="Telegu Second Additional Language">Telegu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Tourism">Tourism</option><option value="Tshivenda Second Additional Language">Tshivenda Second Additional Language</option><option value="Urdu First Additional Language">Urdu First Additional Language</option><option value="Urdu Home Language">Urdu Home Language</option><option value="Urdu Second Additional Language">Urdu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Visual Arts">Visual Arts</option><option value="Xitsonga Second Additional Language">Xitsonga Second Additional Language</option></select></td>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="Subject5APS" name="Subject5APS"><option selected="selected" value="">Select your mark.</option><option value="8">90% - 100% (Level 8)</option><option value="7">80% - 89% (Level 7)</option><option value="6">70% - 79% (Level 6)</option><option value="5">60% - 69% (Level 5)</option><option value="4">50% - 59% (Level 4)</option><option value="3">40% - 49% (Level 3)</option><option value="2">30% - 39% (Level 2)</option><option value="0">0% - 29% (Level 1)</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Subject 6</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="Subject6" name="Subject6"><option selected="selected" value="">Select a subject.</option><option value="Accounting">Accounting</option><option value="Afrikaans Second Additional Language">Afrikaans Second Additional Language</option><option value="Agricultural Management Practices">Agricultural Management Practices</option><option value="Agricultural Science">Agricultural Science</option><option value="Agricultural Technology">Agricultural Technology</option><option value="Arabic Second Additional Language">Arabic Second Additional Language</option><option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option><option value="Civil Technology">Civil Technology</option><option value="Computer Applications Technology">Computer Applications Technology</option><option value="Consumer Studies">Consumer Studies</option><option value="Dance Studies">Dance Studies</option><option value="Design">Design</option><option value="Dramatic Arts">Dramatic Arts</option><option value="Economics">Economics</option><option value="Electrical Technology">Electrical Technology</option><option value="Engineering Graphics and Design">Engineering Graphics and Design</option><option value="English Second Additional Language">English Second Additional Language</option><option value="French Second Additional Language">French Second Additional Language</option><option value="Geography">Geography</option><option value="German Home Language">German Home Language</option><option value="German Second Additional Language">German Second Additional Language</option><option value="Gujarati First Additional Language">Gujarati First Additional Language</option><option value="Gujarati Home Language">Gujarati Home Language</option><option value="Gujarati Second Additional Language">Gujarati Second Additional Language</option><option value="Hebrew Second Additional Language">Hebrew Second Additional Language</option><option value="Hindi First Additional Language">Hindi First Additional Language</option><option value="Hindi Home Language">Hindi Home Language</option><option value="Hindi Second Additional Language">Hindi Second Additional Language</option><option value="History">History</option><option value="Hospitality Studies">Hospitality Studies</option><option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option><option value="IsiNdebele Second Additional Language">IsiNdebele Second Additional Language</option><option value="IsiXhosa Second Additional Language">IsiXhosa Second Additional Language</option><option value="IsiZulu Second Additional Language">IsiZulu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Italian Second Additional Language">Italian Second Additional Language</option><option value="Latin Second Additional Language">Latin Second Additional Language</option><option value="Life Sciences">Life Sciences</option><option value="Mechanical Technology">Mechanical Technology</option><option value="Music">Music</option><option value="Physical Sciences">Physical Sciences</option><option value="Portuguese First Additional Language">Portuguese First Additional Language</option><option value="Portuguese Home Language">Portuguese Home Language</option><option value="Portuguese Second Additional Language">Portuguese Second Additional Language</option><option value="Religion Studies">Religion Studies</option><option value="Sepedi Second Additional Language">Sepedi Second Additional Language</option><option value="Sesotho Second Additional Language">Sesotho Second Additional Language</option><option value="Setswana Second Additional Language">Setswana Second Additional Language</option><option value="SiSwati Second Additional Language">SiSwati Second Additional Language</option><option value="Spanish Second Additional Language">Spanish Second Additional Language</option><option value="Tamil First Additional Language">Tamil First Additional Language</option><option value="Tamil Home Language">Tamil Home Language</option><option value="Tamil Second Additional Language">Tamil Second Additional Language</option><option value="Telegu First Additional Language">Telegu First Additional Language</option><option value="Telegu Home Language">Telegu Home Language</option><option value="Telegu Second Additional Language">Telegu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Tourism">Tourism</option><option value="Tshivenda Second Additional Language">Tshivenda Second Additional Language</option><option value="Urdu First Additional Language">Urdu First Additional Language</option><option value="Urdu Home Language">Urdu Home Language</option><option value="Urdu Second Additional Language">Urdu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Visual Arts">Visual Arts</option><option value="Xitsonga Second Additional Language">Xitsonga Second Additional Language</option></select></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="Subject6APS" name="Subject6APS"><option selected="selected" value="">Select your mark.</option><option value="8">90% - 100% (Level 8)</option><option value="7">80% - 89% (Level 7)</option><option value="6">70% - 79% (Level 6)</option><option value="5">60% - 69% (Level 5)</option><option value="4">50% - 59% (Level 4)</option><option value="3">40% - 49% (Level 3)</option><option value="2">30% - 39% (Level 2)</option><option value="0">0% - 29% (Level 1)</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <strong>Subject 7</strong></td>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="Subject7" name="Subject7"><option selected="selected" value="">Select a subject.</option><option value="Accounting">Accounting</option><option value="Afrikaans Second Additional Language">Afrikaans Second Additional Language</option><option value="Agricultural Management Practices">Agricultural Management Practices</option><option value="Agricultural Science">Agricultural Science</option><option value="Agricultural Technology">Agricultural Technology</option><option value="Arabic Second Additional Language">Arabic Second Additional Language</option><option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option><option value="Civil Technology">Civil Technology</option><option value="Computer Applications Technology">Computer Applications Technology</option><option value="Consumer Studies">Consumer Studies</option><option value="Dance Studies">Dance Studies</option><option value="Design">Design</option><option value="Dramatic Arts">Dramatic Arts</option><option value="Economics">Economics</option><option value="Electrical Technology">Electrical Technology</option><option value="Engineering Graphics and Design">Engineering Graphics and Design</option><option value="English Second Additional Language">English Second Additional Language</option><option value="French Second Additional Language">French Second Additional Language</option><option value="Geography">Geography</option><option value="German Home Language">German Home Language</option><option value="German Second Additional Language">German Second Additional Language</option><option value="Gujarati First Additional Language">Gujarati First Additional Language</option><option value="Gujarati Home Language">Gujarati Home Language</option><option value="Gujarati Second Additional Language">Gujarati Second Additional Language</option><option value="Hebrew Second Additional Language">Hebrew Second Additional Language</option><option value="Hindi First Additional Language">Hindi First Additional Language</option><option value="Hindi Home Language">Hindi Home Language</option><option value="Hindi Second Additional Language">Hindi Second Additional Language</option><option value="History">History</option><option value="Hospitality Studies">Hospitality Studies</option><option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option><option value="IsiNdebele Second Additional Language">IsiNdebele Second Additional Language</option><option value="IsiXhosa Second Additional Language">IsiXhosa Second Additional Language</option><option value="IsiZulu Second Additional Language">IsiZulu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Italian Second Additional Language">Italian Second Additional Language</option><option value="Latin Second Additional Language">Latin Second Additional Language</option><option value="Life Sciences">Life Sciences</option><option value="Mechanical Technology">Mechanical Technology</option><option value="Music">Music</option><option value="Physical Sciences">Physical Sciences</option><option value="Portuguese First Additional Language">Portuguese First Additional Language</option><option value="Portuguese Home Language">Portuguese Home Language</option><option value="Portuguese Second Additional Language">Portuguese Second Additional Language</option><option value="Religion Studies">Religion Studies</option><option value="Sepedi Second Additional Language">Sepedi Second Additional Language</option><option value="Sesotho Second Additional Language">Sesotho Second Additional Language</option><option value="Setswana Second Additional Language">Setswana Second Additional Language</option><option value="SiSwati Second Additional Language">SiSwati Second Additional Language</option><option value="Spanish Second Additional Language">Spanish Second Additional Language</option><option value="Tamil First Additional Language">Tamil First Additional Language</option><option value="Tamil Home Language">Tamil Home Language</option><option value="Tamil Second Additional Language">Tamil Second Additional Language</option><option value="Telegu First Additional Language">Telegu First Additional Language</option><option value="Telegu Home Language">Telegu Home Language</option><option value="Telegu Second Additional Language">Telegu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Tourism">Tourism</option><option value="Tshivenda Second Additional Language">Tshivenda Second Additional Language</option><option value="Urdu First Additional Language">Urdu First Additional Language</option><option value="Urdu Home Language">Urdu Home Language</option><option value="Urdu Second Additional Language">Urdu Second Additional Language</option><option value="Visual Arts">Visual Arts</option><option value="Xitsonga Second Additional Language">Xitsonga Second Additional Language</option></select></td>
                <td style="background-color: #e7ecf9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="Subject7APS" name="Subject7APS"><option selected="selected" value="">Select your mark.</option><option value="8">90% - 100% (Level 8)</option><option value="7">80% - 89% (Level 7)</option><option value="6">70% - 79% (Level 6)</option><option value="5">60% - 69% (Level 5)</option><option value="4">50% - 59% (Level 4)</option><option value="3">40% - 49% (Level 3)</option><option value="2">30% - 39% (Level 2)</option><option value="0">0% - 29% (Level 1)</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="btn btn-default" onclick="return(validateform(this))" onkeypress="return(DetectEnterPressed(event))" type="submit" value="Calculate APS" /></td>
                <td align="center" id="showScore">
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you would probably be better off working out why the form calculator doesn't work with aggregation turned on.

Comment: I just assumed it was the advanced css/js aggregation module performing aggregation or compression?

Comment: it would be, but it sounds to me like it may be easier to find out why the form isn't working with aggregation turned on rather than bypassing the aggregation, this is of course an assumption as you have not posted any code or what errors are reported in the browser console.

Comment: @user3616622 like suggested by 2pha you need to make a code review of your custom JS , you probably made a mistake or code standard not respected